# Using 'await' and 'async' correctly in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have this piece of code:

```
function func(x) {
    return func2(x)
        .then((result) => {
            let a = await func3(result.a);
            let b = await func3(result.b);
            return {'a': a, 'b': b};
        });
}
```

And I need to put `async()` somewhere, but I am unable to figure out where.

I tried before the `=>` and after the `=>`, but I got a syntax error in both cases.

P.S, if I use it in the declaration of `func`, then I get a runtime error `await is a reserved word`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to achieve something like that

```
function func(x) {
    return func2(x)
        .then(async (result) => {
            let a = await func3(result.a);
            let b = await func3(result.b);
            return {'a': a, 'b': b};
        });
}
```

or

```
async function func(x) {
    const result = await func2(x)
    let a = await func3(result.a);
    let b = await func3(result.b);
    return {'a': a, 'b': b};
}
```

Considering your edited question, it seems that you are using a version of `nodejs` that does not support `async/await`

Comment: Just added info on that (before I saw your answer).

Comment: Oh wait, I see you have an additional `await` there, which I haven't tried... Nope, that doesn't help either. I still get `await is a reserved word`.

Comment: Which version of node are you using ?

Comment: It should be ok. I'm sorry I have no more idea

Comment: FYI: You would get `await is a reserved word` only when the function using `await` is not an `async` function.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
function func(x) {
    return func2(x)
        .then((result) => {
            let a = async() => {await func3(result.a)};
            let b = async() => {await func3(result.b)};
            return {'a': a, 'b': b};
        });
}
```